# Integrating okta-spring-boot re-directs me to a 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, okta

I am trying to integrate okta-spring-boot into my existing Spring Boot application (using version 1.4.0) using my corporate okta instance and OpenID.

I can get the server to run, and when I visit localhost:8080, I get re-directed to my corporate okta, but it's a 404 page.

404 error screenshot

[image: 1]

My application.properties looks like this

```
okta.oauth2.issuer=https://someCorp.okta.com
okta.oauth2.client-id=xxxx
okta.oauth2.client-secret=xxxx
okta.oauth2.redirect-uri=/authorization-code/callback
```

It seems like the issuer should be https://someCorp.okta.com/oauth2/default but the engineer I am working with on the corporate okta side says https://someCorp.okta.com should work no problem.

Here is a look at my SpringSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v1/info", "/v1/healthcheck", "/docs/**", "/metrics")
                .permitAll().requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().oauth2Client()
                .and().oauth2Login();
        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

The https://someCorp.okta.com/.well-known/openid-configuration lists the issuer as {"issuer": "https://someCorp.okta.com"}

Is there something I am doing wrong here? Thanks so much

Comment: What is the URL path for the page that shows the 404?

Comment: This is the URL

https://someCorp.okta.com/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxx&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20address%20phone%20offline_access%20groups&state=SRLJzHljddodY_tMOnFmosJqm8CqMfdKzCVQZbuJArw%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/authorization-code/callback&nonce=RBXElsdb29w24r5iwyt9ibHpNZwU7MYDJELcDg8NMQE

Thanks!

Comment: so far so good, can you list the relevant bits from your pom.xml/gradle file (versions of spring, okta, etc)